# nginx proxy pass without redirect

Tags: nginx, proxy, configuration, proxypass

Hi i'm struggling with this issue for some time all examples I found don't work.

I want to proxy a video on a remote server. This video is a stream so not a actual file;

I was thinking something like this:

```
location ~ /video/(.*) {

    set $url_args = "?id=$1&key=myverysecretkey";

    gzip off;
    gzip_static_off;

    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 120;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_buffer_size 20m;
    proxy_buffers 24 20m;

    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass https://videourl_from_server.com/?$url_args;

}
```

But the problem is, it only redirects to the URL. And that is not what I want since I can do that myself ;)
I want it to proxy stream the data from the other server.

Comment: `it only redirects to the URL` probably because that is the response sent back from the server you are proxying. Unless you own `video on a remote server` you probably shouldn't be doing that anyway.

Comment: mmmmm ok. But when Twitter was blocked in Turkey, people also proxied Twitter to support them. Technically it should be possible,